# Link external files in index.html using Webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

So I'm kinda new in this webpack thing. Right now my project looks something like this

```
|- package.json
|- webpack.config.js
|- /dist
  |- index.html
  |- bundle.js
|- /src
  |- index.js
|- /node_modules
```

I'm including bundle.js in my index.html file usign a < script > tag. Now I want to move index.html to my project's root since I don't want to include /dist folder in my repository, however the new bundle.js path < script src="dist/bundle.js"> seems not to work anymore.
Does anybody know how can I include files from different folders in index.html or what other options could I use in order to have it working?

EDIT

I did not move bundle.js since it's created/updated everytime you run npm run build. So I want my proyect to look something like this

```
|- package.json
|- webpack.config.js
|- index.html
|- /dist
  |- bundle.js
|- /src
  |- index.js
|- /node_modules
```

Comment: Did you also move `bundle.js` to your root, or did you only move `.index.html`?

Comment: Just index.html since bundle.js is created when you run the build

Comment: Then assuming your `<script>` tag inside of `index.html` references `'dist/bundle.js'`, it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `<script src="dist/bundle.js">` that is a **relative** link. You're specifying that the `bundle.js` file exists in a folder called `dist` that is a **sibling** of the file you are including it from (`index.html`).

After you move these two files, I assume your structure now looks like this:

```
|- package.json
|- webpack.config.js
|- /dist /* Unwanted */
|- bundle.js
|- index.html
|- /src
  |- index.js
|- /node_modules
```

As such, you no longer need the `dist` part of the URL, and have three options:

- You can use the **relative link** `bundle.js` to state that `bundle.js` is in the same folder as `index.html`
- You can use the **root-relative link** `/bundle.js` to reference the bundle relative to the root (note the preceding slash)
- You can use the **absolute link** `https://example.com/bundle.js` to either load a hosted version or reference your own site absolutely

For further reading on relative and absolute URLs, I recommend checking out this **[Coffee Cup article](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)**.

Hvaing said that, note that in order to simply 'ignore' your `dist` folder from your repository, you may be looking for `.gitignore`. If you set up a `.gitignore` file in the root of your project, and simply type `dist/` into it, your Git will automatically exclude the `dist` folder and all files contained within from your commits.

Hope this helps! :)